# Tomcat Manager and "Empty" Sessions

Tags: session, tomcat7

We are trying to work on some performance issues we are having where our Tomcat server just stops responding to incoming requests.  One thing we have noticed is that when you open the Tomcat Manager and look at the sessions for our webapp, there are lots of "blank sessions."  By that I mean sessions that have no "used time" and the "creation time" / "last accessed time" match.  Then when clicking on the session Id, the is only one attribute called "tasks" that has a {} for the value.  I do not know what is creating these, but I know there are lots of them.  I just was curious if anyone has seen this before, and might know what causes this.

Running Tomcat 7.0.29.

Thank you for your time.